# Help is needed for a limit question $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum^{n}_{k=1}\frac{1}{ \binom{n}{k}}$

Tags: limits, summation, binomial-coefficients, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum^{n}_{k=1}\frac{1}{ \binom{n}{k}}$$

Comment: Is $C_n^k = \binom{k}{n}$?

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{\binom{k}{n}}$? If that is the case, then one has $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{\binom{k}{n}}=1$ since $\dbinom{k}{n}=0$ for all $k<n$, and hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{\binom{k}{n}}=1$.

Comment: sorry,$C_n^k＝\binom{n}{k}$, do you have any idea? thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for Lower bound

Let $$ a_{n} = \sum^{n}_{k=1}\frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}} = \frac{1}{\binom{n}{1}}+\sum^{n-2}_{k=2}\frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}}+\frac{1}{\binom{n}{n-1}}+\frac{1}{\binom{n}{n}}\geq 1+\frac{2}{n}$$

and for upper bound  $$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}}.$$ Then $$a_n=1+\frac{2}{n}+ \sum_{k=2}^{n-2}\frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}}\le 1+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{n-3}{\binom{n}{2}}=1+\frac{4}{n}.\frac{n-2}{n-1}$$

Now $n\rightarrow \infty$ and $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}}=1.$$